# What conditions does it take for two materials to break equally?

Tags: material-science

Consider having two panes of glass, of equal size.

Theoretically, **what conditions does it take so that it becomes possible to have them break with exactly the same pattern when applying force to a given point?**

You can apply this question to more than just glass panes, e.g.

- Chocolate bars
- Wood
- Bricks

What conditions play an important role in the breaking of any material?

Comment: Crack propagation during brittle fracture of real materials is stochastic. Very small differences in internal stresses change it radically.

Comment: "exactly the same pattern" is a bit vague definition. You need to be a bit more clear about the scale. If you expect  "exactly the same pattern" for example in atomic scale say for a crack of 1 mm then there is no way you can achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I want „exactly the same“ - I know that it is not achievable practically, but I want to know more about the theoretical circumstances under which something like this would be possible.

Comment: Of course, „exactly the same“ is very different from „looks exactly the same“, Which means „exactly the same“ on macroscopic scale, but not necessarily microscopically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *theory*, to have the *exact* same fracture, you need the *exact same* material on the atomic level.

All the different discontinuities/defects in the material pattern would have to be *identical*.  Basically, there is some sort of atomic structure that is likely not uniform throughout the whole solid.

These variations in atomic structure will determine what locations are most likely to fracture first; and how the fracture will propagate through the rest of the structure.  The only way to ensure that two fractures are identical, would be to have two *identical* pieces of material; with all the same sub-atomic arrangements.  Then you would also have to apply the force at the *exact same* location.

Basically, fractures depend on microscopic and sub-microscopic structures of the materials.  Unless the two objects are identical down to the sub-microscopic level; and the applied load is identical; you would not get the same fracture.

So note; this is extremely limited *in theory*.  In practice; it would be near, or entirely, impossible.

Comment: How about magnetic fields/air pressure/etc?

Comment: @NikxDa I consider that all part of the applied load.  You would need full control over everything it is experiencing from external sources.  You wouldn't be able to assume anything is negligible.

Comment: So there is not a single factor that is negligible?

Comment: @NikxDa Not if you want _exact_ copies of the crack pattern.  Any small variations will have at least small effects on the crack propagation.  If there were some limit of acceptable variation; other conditions could be relaxed as well; but you wanted exactly identical crack propagation.

Comment: @NikxDa If you want to hand-write an *exact* copy of a large book, such as the Bible, such that new copy is exactly the same as the first, is there any letter in the book which is negligible?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was unsure whether stuff like athmospheric pressure would really affect the outcome or if it simply wouldn‘t matter.

Answer (score 0):

There are theritical ways to do this and as we set at the start the real crack propagation can be much more complex.

If your glass panels are square or rectangular they will break along the 2 diagonals from corner to corner, if you apply the load near the center of plate, because this is the least ultimate cracking work (load multiplied by displacement at failure). There are many ways to calculate the ultimate work done along a failure line in a plate.

If the glass panels are polygons or have random shapes like L or K, then what you do is assume a few reasonably possible patterns of cracking and calculate the energy it takes to break along those patterns, and compare the results.

The pattern with the lowest energy is the pattern any glass panel of that shape will break.

Comment: That wouldn't guarantee the exact same patterns; just similar/approximately the same.